# Add .dot to file download

Tags: html, symfony

I'm trying to make a download link. When I just place a downloads folder in my web directory and put the file in it, which is this case is cv.docx. It's ok until you click on download. It creates a cv.docx.dot

Here's my code:

```
<a href="{{ asset('../downloads/cv.docx') }}" download="cv.docx">Download CV</a>
```

EDIT:
The problem seems to only persist in Safari on MacOS, it works in chrome and firefox...

Comment: What is the URL you're getting in the `href`?

Comment: the custom `download` tag attribute suggests you are using some sort of plug-in of some framework? Maybe `jQuery` or something similar?

Comment: href="../downloads/cv.docx" this is what the inspector shows me. and the download attribute i got from another stack overflow, but doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem. It seems to be a problem with the apache server running on Mac OS. And the problem only persist with Safari. Once you upload the website to a real server, (not the local mac one) then its all fine....

Answer (score 0):

Atribute [download](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) is not supported on Safari yet.

You will have to set filename on header like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename"');
```

Comment: but it works when i put the website on the online webhosting server.